# CDI not available exception deploying a SpringFramework application to Payara

Tags: payara

I have a very simple java webapp with a Hello World servlet. It deploys fine. But, when I add the dependency for SpringFramework 6.0.0 WEB jar file, I get two errors in the Payara (most recent version) logs. I’m using Java 17.

Maven dependency:

> org.springframework
>       spring-web
>       6.0.0

Errors:

There’s a slew of these error messages:

> Exception while visiting org/springframework/aot/generate/GeneratedClasses$Owner.class of size 2205
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Record requires ASM8
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitRecordComponent(ClassVisitor.java:305)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readRecordComponent(ClassReader.java:953)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:731)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:164)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:130)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflec[2022-11-18T10:29:09.444-0500] [Payara 6.2022.1] [SEVERE] [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] [tid: _ThreadID=176 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1668785349444] [levelValue: 1000] [[
> Critical error during deployment:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available
> at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getCdiBeanManager(Util.java:1493)
> at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.addCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:192)
> at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:164)
> at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:416)
> at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.performOneTimeELInitialization(ExpressionLanguage.java:144)
> at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.getELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:89)
> at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:200)
> at com.sun.faces.el.ELContextImpl.(ELContextImpl.java:60)
> at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5172)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:681)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5750)
> t.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)…

And then a few of these:

> [2022-11-18T10:29:09.444-0500] [Payara 6.2022.1] [SEVERE] [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] [tid: _ThreadID=176 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1668785349444] [levelValue: 1000] [[
> Critical error during deployment:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDI is not available
> at com.sun.faces.util.Util.getCdiBeanManager(Util.java:1493)
> at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.addCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:192)
> at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:164)
> at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:416)
> at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.performOneTimeELInitialization(ExpressionLanguage.java:144)
> at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.getELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:89)
> at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getELResolver(ApplicationImpl.java:200)
> at com.sun.faces.el.ELContextImpl.(ELContextImpl.java:60)
> at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5172)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:681)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5750)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:941)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1813)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1565)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
> at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
> at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:292)
> at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:361)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:630)
> at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:616)

Remove the dependency from Sprngframework web and the app deploys fine. Saw another similar post on Stackoverflow and followed it's suggestions, but nothing worked. Have posted this problem on Payara with NO response.

Answer (score 3):

After weeks of beating my head against a wall and trying all kinds of solutions, I wrote to one of the SpringFramework developers, Juergen Hoeller. Here's his response.....

Sorry to hear that there is so much trouble on Payara still. We also have corresponding reports on GitHub:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29718
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29743
Unfortunately neither of the two is an actual problem to be solved on Spring's own side, as far as I can see.

With the CDI issue, it's Payara's CDI implementation not being able to parse Java 17's new record types.
Also, I wonder why Payara needs to parse every single deployed class file if you are not actually using CDI.
It might be possible to turn that off, but at the very least, Payara should defensively handle "unknown" types.

With the Hibernate issue, it's a problem with Hibernate 6 initializing its Jackson configuration on Payara.
There does not seem to be a StAX provider available, and Hibernate insists on one being present for Jackson.

Overall, this needs to be taken to Payara and Hibernate, we are not aware of anything Spring can do better.
Feel free to add further comments to the GitHub issues in case there is anything we can do from our side!
Even if our focus is on Tomcat/Jetty these days, we of course want Spring 6 to work fine on Payara as well.

Thanks for your efforts to try to make this work,

Juergen

So now we have to report this to Oracle's Glassfish developers and Payara's developers. In the meantime, gonna try another web server.